# Google Cloud Message API Notification Data doesn't appear - PHP

Tags: php, curl, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

im sending notifications to my clients with PHP. Here is my PHP Code for this

```
<?php

define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyAYq7KpB5J7x3p3zYyna...' );
$registrationId = array( $_GET['id'] );

$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationId,
    'notification'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

When i execute the script with my registration id there is notification like this, [Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYlwc.png)

**Title is** *Push message*
**Body is** *The Message*

As you can see, Notification title and message body is not equal with mines. How i can fix this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$msg` should be a JSON object, as indicated in the [Messaging Concepts and Options](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

{
"to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
"data" : {
"Nick" : "Mario",
"body" : "great match!",
"Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
},
}

For a more detailed discussion regarding Downstream Messaging, you can refer to its [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server) were it discusses various aspects of sending messages.

Comment: The json parameter "to" is not working. "registration_ids" is working fine.
I tried to encode message with json but still same issue.